# Couchbase lite querying and filtering

Tags: android, sqlite, xamarin, couchbase-lite, nosql

I was just testing couchbase lite on android (using xamarin).
Maybe it is a repeated question; is couchbase lite made to be a NoSql alternative for SQLite or it is a small couch that is optimized for syncing with the main couchbase database?

Querying is done by views(indexes) and they seems to be static searches using constants which have small changes at all.

For example can I use it with an autocomplete text or a search with data that users enter during the runtime?. N1QL seems to be a way to do this but it is not planned to be brought to mobile.

If I haven't used it in a correct way or I didn't understand couchbase mechanism, please tell me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> N1QL seems to be a way to do this but it is not planned to be brought to mobile.

Actually, this is one of the features of 2.0.  It is not N1QL exactly but it is meant to be as close as we can get to it.  You can see some examples of the syntax in the [tests](https://github.com/couchbase/couchbase-lite-net/blob/feature/api-v2/src/Couchbase.Lite.Tests.Shared/QueryTest.cs).  Ignore the stuff on top (model) because that will apply to later 2.x releases and focus on the stuff that starts with `Query.Select`

As for the other things, you can use Couchbase Lite for a fully offline database as a NoSQL alternative to using SQLite directly if you wish.  You can also use it to sync with Couchbase Server which is where a lot of the real power comes from!

Comment: Thanks. When v2 will be released?

Comment: Current timeline is:  We're targeting a beta at the end of the summer with GA by end of the year.  But we have been releasing [developer builds](https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/mobile/2.0/whatsnew.html) for the community to try out every two weeks for a few months now!

Comment: To make it really clear, Couchbase Lite is built from scratch for mobile.  It's not in any way a trimmed down version of Couchbase Server.